# Codeigniter: use auth in core base controller is it a good practice?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-3

im doing this;

example core/MY_CONTROLLER.php

```
private $action_user=null;
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    ##listen for post attempts;
    $this->validate();

    ##set action_user; return null if no session else return user object
    $this->action_user = $this->session->userdata('loged_user');

    ##extra check step
    if($this->user->pwd_has_changed($this->action_user)){
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            alerts('error','the password you used to login has changed ! please relogin');
            return $this->failed_login();
    }
}

public function alerts(){return die(json_encode(alerts()));}#a helper function.. just ignore it for this example
public function logout(){$this->session->sess_destroy();redirect();}


#AUTH
private function failed_login(){
    //$callers=debug_backtrace();

    alerts('warning','failed login');//.' '.$callers[1]['function']);
    ob_clean();//clear flush just to make sure !

    if($this->input->is_ajax_request())$this->load->view('base/ajax/landing');
    else $this->load->view('base/landing');

    die($this->output->get_output());//kill request and load landing in same uri. this in case he attempt login again he will be at same url; also helps with partials views
}
private function success_login(){
    unset($_POST['login'],$_POST['password']);
    alerts('success','welcome '.$this->action_user->login);
    //nothin much to do.. just dont die
}
private function validate(){
    //listen to posts if so logout and relog in
    if( !$this->input->post('login') || !$this->input->post('password'))return FALSE;
    $this->session->sess_destroy();#destroy session
    #1. validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('login', 'User Login', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');

    #1.2 Failed validation
    if( ! $this->form_validation->run() )return alerts('error',$this->form_validation->error_string(),false);#set message and return false

    #2. Login
    $this->user->login(set_value('login'),set_value('password'));
    //i dont want it to return anything ! $this->user->login should set messages of success OR fail + set user session
}
public function auth($role = null){
    if(!isset($this->action_user->id))
        return alerts('error',"this is a users restricted area",$this->failed_login());

    //ACCESS LEVELS CONDITIONS
    if($this->user->in_group($this->action_user->id,$role))return $this->success_login();

    return alerts('error',"this is a {$role} restricted area",$this->failed_login());
}
#END AUTH
```

now in my controller constructor; since MY_CONTROLLER constructor is called first; so i should hv retrieved $action_user object; or already attempted to log him in.

if i want to restrict a page i just add

```
$this->auth();
//or $this->auth('admin');
```

to its constructor and if user is not allowed page will die and send him my view page without redirect;

the reason im using such approach is let user be able to login,logout from any controller;
if he visit `http://localhost/RANDOMECONTROLLER/logout` he will still logout.. same for login.

also its helpful that sometimes when i get page partials by ajax; it will just return a landing page into this div with login form.

example

a statistics page have 4 widgets, 1 of them is only viewable by admin;
then when ajax fitch 4 widgets, it will show 3 and a div with login form saying you need to be an admin to login..

...

so do you think this is a good way to do this ? or is it bug gable spaghetti **** ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practice. The best practice is to create a Secure_Controller that extends MY_Controller. If you have a controller with auth you need to extend Secure_Controller, but if you have another without auth you need yo extend MY_Controller.

There are lots of libraries for codeigniter auth easy to extend and adapt to your requirements, for example [Ion Auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth).

Comment: any reason why its not good practice ? and why would i use a heavy lib that utilize 4 tables for simple auth? and even if i did use one; this will replace my model yet my question is about core base controller

Comment: The reason is that if you put auth functionality in MY_Controller, you assume that all your future controllers will need auth, and that's  not a good design because probably in the future you will create a controller without auth functionality but needing MY_Controller functionality.

Comment: It's util to use that "heavy" lib because you have to write 0 lines of code using it and because it's maintained by users searching for bugs and new functionalities.

Comment: A good practice is create classes with determined roles, for example a class for manage auth, a class for the database access... Auth must be managed by a class or controller created for that task specifically.

Comment: i agree with all that; and thats why i have `$this->user` to handle auth; and for a page to require auth i must include `$this->auth();` command in constructor -as i mentioned- , yet its a good point regarding maintained lib.

Comment: So MY_Controller only handles the auth? I was thinking MY_Controller will have more functionality.

Comment: https://github.com/alzalabany/codeigniter-base-controller; so far it handle directing auth requests, and template generating and assets management